# Android P background restrictions for VoIP apps

Tags: android, permissions, background, voip, android-9.0-pie

With enhanced privacy solutions added in Android P, one of them being [no access to microphone or camera when the app is on the background](https://developer.android.com/preview/behavior-changes), I've been testing my VoIP app and can confirm that indeed the microphone goes out after a few seconds of multitasking (while on a call). Binding a service didn't change this behavior either.

However, I feel like this is detrimental to the VoIP app community as often, while on a call, the user will multitask sending our app to the background.

Has Google come out, or is anyone aware of special conditions, flags, or practices for keeping the microphone alive for backgrounded VoIP apps on Android P (while on an call)?

Thank you!

Comment: Doesnt using foreground service exempt from being backgrounded, ergo not havimg mic takem away?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63130222/access-microphone-in-android-9-while-the-app-is-in-the-background