# How to always use the microphone on android 11, even in the background

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-11

I want my app to always use the microphone even when the app is closed. I already use a foreground service, but when I close the app the record audio permission gets revoked because of android 11s new permission system that only allows microphone use when the app is open. Is there a way to let the app use the mic even when it is closed?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access microphone in android 9 while the app is in the background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63130222/access-microphone-in-android-9-while-the-app-is-in-the-background)

Comment: Hi, Rounded Infinity, have managed to solve the issue?

Comment: What seems to be new behavior with Android 11 is that you also have to ensure that startForeground with a notification was called -before- you attempt to access the mic.